# WCF service object is null - on one particular PC

Tags: javascript, wcf, service, null

*When JavaScript instantiates a WCF service for a particular machine, it throws this JavaScript error.  However, the WCF service works for other machines on a different network.  I'm thinking that a port is being blocked, but that's a hunch.  If you have any ideas, please shoot them over.*

**JavaScript Error:**

Message: 'LIMS.UI.Web.WCFServices.Accessioning' is null or not an object

**The JavaScript crashes on this line:**

var service = new LIMS.UI.Web.WCFServices.Accessioning.QuickDataEntryService();

**Here is a snippet of my code:**

...

```
PreAccessioningLoad: function(sender) {

    if (this.Elements.TxtSampleId.value != "") {

        **var service = new LIMS.UI.Web.WCFServices.Accessioning.QuickDataEntryService();**
        jQuery(this.Elements.ImageAjaxSpinner).css("visibility", "visible");
        service.PreAccessioningLoad(this.Elements.TxtSampleId.value, Function.createDelegate(this, this.PreAccessioningLoadSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.PreAccessioningLoadError));
    }
    return false;  //prevent page postback
},
PreAccessioningLoadSuccess: function(quickDataEntryObject) {

    var val = jQuery(this.Elements.TxtSampleId).val().replace(/^\s\s*/, "").replace(/\s\s*$/, "");  // trim spaces 
    var intRegex = /^\d{1,10}$/;
    if (!intRegex.test(val)) {
        jQuery(this.Elements.SampleIdAjaxValidate).html("<span style='color:red'>Sample Id must contain between 1 and 10 digits</span>");
        jQuery(this.Elements.ImageAjaxSpinner).css("visibility", "hidden");
        jQuery(this.Elements.TxtSampleId).focus();  // triggers unwanted blur event
        return false;
    }
    else {
        jQuery(this.Elements.SampleIdAjaxValidate).html("");  // clear AJAX validation
    }

    if (quickDataEntryObject.Success == true) {

        // set the hidden field to true so that we know to call the dbo.procPreAccessioningSave stored procedure
        // this will be checked on a full page postback when they click Save Test and Sample
        jQuery(this.Elements.HiddenContainsPreAccessioningData).val("true");

        this._internalClientId = quickDataEntryObject.ClientId;
        jQuery(this.Elements.TxtClientId).val(quickDataEntryObject.ClientIdentifyingNumber);
        jQuery(this.Elements.DDLClientName).val(quickDataEntryObject.ClientIdentifyingNumber);

        var thisTemp = this;
        jQuery(thisTemp.Elements.DDLTest).children("option").each(function() {
            jQuery(this).remove();
        });

        jQuery.each(quickDataEntryObject.TestPricingOptionsList, function(i) {
            var key = quickDataEntryObject.TestPricingOptionsList[i].Key
            var val = quickDataEntryObject.TestPricingOptionsList[i].Value
            jQuery(thisTemp.Elements.DDLTest).append(jQuery("<option></option>").val(key).text(val));
        });
        jQuery(this.Elements.DDLTest).val(quickDataEntryObject.TestPricingOptionId);

        //jQuery(this.Elements.ClientNameLabel).html("<b>Client: </b> [" + quickDataEntryObject.ClientIdentifyingNumber + "] " + quickDataEntryObject.ClientName);
        //jQuery(this.Elements.TestLabel).html("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Test Requested: </b> [" + quickDataEntryObject.TestPricingOptionId + "] " + quickDataEntryObject.TestPricingOptionName);
        //jQuery(this.Elements.TestLabel).html("<b>Test Requested: </b> " + quickDataEntryObject.TestPricingOptionName);

        //jQuery(this.Elements.DDLClientName).css("visibility", "hidden");
        //jQuery(this.Elements.DDLTest).css("visibility", "hidden");
        //jQuery(this.Elements.ClientIdLabelDiv).css("visibility", "hidden");
        //jQuery(this.Elements.ClientIdDiv).css("visibility", "hidden");
        //jQuery(this.Elements.TestIdDiv).css("visibility", "hidden");
        //jQuery(this.Elements.ClientNameLabelDiv).css("visibility", "hidden");
        //jQuery(this.Elements.TestLabelDiv).css("visibility", "hidden");

        jQuery(this.Elements.LabelPreAccessioningData).html("<b><i>This Sample Id contains Pre-Accessioning Data</i></b>");
        jQuery(this.Elements.TxtClientId).attr('readonly', 'true');
        jQuery(this.Elements.DDLClientName).attr('disabled', 'disabled');

        //jQuery("form:input:disabled[disabled='true']").css("color", "#ff0000");

    }
    else {

        jQuery(this.Elements.HiddenContainsPreAccessioningData).val("false");

        //jQuery(this.Elements.DDLClientName).css("visibility", "hidden");
        //jQuery(this.Elements.DDLTest).css("visibility", "hidden");

        jQuery(this.Elements.ClientNameLabel).html("");
        jQuery(this.Elements.TestLabel).html("");

        //jQuery(this.Elements.DDLClientName).css("visibility", "visible");
        //jQuery(this.Elements.DDLTest).css("visibility", "visible");
        //jQuery(this.Elements.ClientIdLabelDiv).css("visibility", "visible");
        //jQuery(this.Elements.ClientIdDiv).css("visibility", "visible");
        //jQuery(this.Elements.TestIdDiv).css("visibility", "visible");
        //jQuery(this.Elements.ClientNameLabelDiv).css("visibility", "visible");
        //jQuery(this.Elements.TestLabelDiv).css("visibility", "visible");
        jQuery(this.Elements.LabelPreAccessioningData).html("");
        jQuery(this.Elements.TxtClientId).removeAttr('readonly');
        jQuery(this.Elements.DDLClientName).removeAttr('disabled');

        //var thisTemp = this;
        //jQuery(thisTemp.Elements.DDLTest).children("option").each(function() {
        //    jQuery(this).remove();
        //});

        // Omega wants the client and default test to persist
        //jQuery(this.Elements.TxtClientId).val("");
        //jQuery(this.Elements.DDLClientName).val(0);

        // ideally we should get the default "Test Requested" here... call another AJAX query and select the default test or store the default in the object
    }
    //jQuery(this.Elements.TxtLAN).focus();

    jQuery(this.Elements.ImageAjaxSpinner).css("visibility", "hidden");
    return false;
},
PreAccessioningLoadError: function(sender) {

    jQuery(this.Elements.ImageAjaxSpinner).css("visibility", "hidden");
    alert("error");  // need to develop an error service for error handling and log the error to the log table!
    return false;
},
```

...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The customer was using https, not http.  It was that simple.  It had nothing to do with ports.  When I gave them the link to test whether the *.svc worked, there was no issue, which gave me a hunch.  After they tested that URL, I had them immediately go in and test the workflow again.  And it did.

I converted them to https today.  I'll post some more information later for the steps I followed with making WCF work with a certificate for those interested.